# Looking for a library to an email from my email to another email, and passing javascript variables

Tags: library, javascript, java, email

I'm trying to set up a method of filling out an online form (in javascript), and having that data email to my mothers business email so that she can contact them or  other stuff. I'm decent at Java, Javascript, and C++, so bonus points if its within those languages. I am willing to learn others though. I am by know means a professional and If you have any other questions lemme know. If you have a better way of doing this or a way that easier, id be happy to hear suggestions.

Thank you.

Comment: If you have a moment, would you mind improving the title of this question?  It makes my head spin. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Back in "the old days" you could have a simple HTML form with the `method` set to `mailto` and the browser would kick in the system mail client and send it on.  Never really worked well (this was mid/late 90s).

What you really want to do is use JavaScript on the client side to validate teh data (maybe) and then submit it via `post` to a webserver hosted script that runs server side and sends the email.

Plenty of Free, free, and pay-for solutions out there in a variety of languages, or you can write your own - I've done them in Perl, PHP, and Java and know others who have done them in Python and even Visual Basic (as a CGI script on an Windows+Apache setup).  But to give a recommendation we'd need to know what OS the server is running and what languages/technology stacks are available (ie, LAMP, MEAN, Tomcat+Java, etc)